# Dropped my Mac on the floor. Hard Disk doesn't work

Tags: mac, hard-drive

Just dropped my MacBook Pro on the floor. It doesn't book from the disk anymore I tried what is suggested here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1440 
with no success.

Any ideas what I can do about it now?

Worst case how to recover some of the data on the MacBook?

Comment: Unless you disabled it, MacBooks contain a "G sensor" which is supposed to detect when one is dropped and automagically park the drive heads in the hopes of preventing damage to the drive. So I'd be surprised if the drive was dead. How hard of a banging did it get when it hit whatever it hit? Is there obvious physical damage? Chipped plastic, for example.

Comment: The drop wasn't from a high place (about 1 feet) and it worked a bit after that and then stopped. I tried to boot from the DVD and tries to "repair disk" but it said the disk can't be repaired..It didn't really have damage but the it's a bit older model so I've used it for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if you were to say this to anyone, they would 99% of the time say straight away that the problem is with the hard drive (as you have also said).

Most Apple products I have dealt with are built quite snug and cramped, the hard drive is screwed down and really does not have much room to move around so I doubt that it has just come out.

As Josh K has said, the first thing should be to take it to Apple as they may honour the warranty on it and provide a free fix. If you were to open it up yourself, you may lose any future warranty on unrelated issues.

However, if Apple do not honour the warranty or want to charge a repair fee (usually quite extortionate) then as long as you know what you are doing, buy yourself a new laptop drive, any speed (5400/7200RPM) and any size of matching interface (most likely any 2.5" Sata drive will work).

Then just load OSX on as a fresh install and you should be as good as new.

As for recovering data, you may be out of luck. If it is very important, go to a specialist. If however you want to try yourself, once you have it out, plug it in to any working computer and I would personally use [R-Studio](http://www.r-studio.com/) (not free). There are other tools out there, but I haven't tested them with hard drives used in Apple machines.

Answer (score 2):

Open it up and reseat the drive or drive cable. It's possible that the impact knocked it loose.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that  but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Take it to Apple. Assuming it's under warranty (AppleCare) they can normally do a lot to fix any issues. It's possible the drive head scratched the drives, as mentioned something could have been knocked loose as well. My experience is more often the controller board will have an issue then the actually hard drive.

Comment: It's been more than 3 years so my AppleCare has expired!

Comment: @Tam: That's unfortunate. I think they will still take a look and diagnose for free, but I've never had a computer out of warranty before.